# Will other vampires attack me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Since I'm a vampire, will other vampires attack me or be friendly to me?

Comment: Are you a vampire, or a Vampire Lord (in the Dawnguard DLC)?

Answer (score 5):

The hostile vampires will still attack you, as if you're a non-vampire. See the [UESP wiki article about vampire types](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vampire#Vampire_Types), to see which kinds of enemy vampire NPCs these are. Generally, these non-named vampire NPCs don't discriminate between vampire and non-vampire player characters. [Named vampire NPCs'](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vampire#Named_Vampires) hostility towards you will depend on their respective related quests and your [disposition](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Disposition) towards them.

Also, see the list of [Hostile Encounters](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:World_Interactions#Hostile_Encounters) at UESP wiki. Notice that all of the hostile encounters with vampires will still have vampires attacking you even if you're a vampire yourself.